# LINQ search from multiple tables using entity framework core

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-core

I have to select list of values based on like conditions on the mutiple tables from the azure SQL server. When I trying to search a values from the DB. I'm getting the following error during the execution.

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the
>   operation or the server is not responding. The statement has been
>   terminated

```
private IQueryable<UserProfile> UserProfileDetailsConditionalQuery(string query, bool? isActive)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime dateInput;
            bool isDate = DateTime.TryParse(query, out dateInput);

            return from ub in idamDbContext.UserBasicInfo
                   join ur in idamDbContext.UserRoles on ub.UserId equals ur.UserBasicInfoId
                   join rl in idamDbContext.Role on ur.RoleId equals rl.Id                       
                   join t in idamDbContext.Territory on ub.TerritoryId equals t.Id
                   into territory
                   from leftTerritory in territory.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   where (ub.FirstName.ToUpper().Contains(query.ToUpper())
                         || ub.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(query.ToUpper())
                         || ub.Email.ToUpper().Contains(query.ToUpper())
                         || rl.Description.ToUpper().Contains(query.ToUpper())
                         || leftTerritory.Name.ToUpper().Contains(query.ToUpper())
                         || (isDate && ub.Created.Value.Date.Equals(query)))
                         && ((isActive != null) ? ub.IsActive == isActive : (ub.IsActive == true || ub.IsActive == false))
                   orderby ub.Created descending, rl.Created descending
                   select new UserProfile()
                   {
                       UserId = ub.UserId,
                       FirstName = ub.FirstName,
                       LastName = ub.LastName,
                       EmailId = ub.Email,
                       UserRole = (from r in idamDbContext.Role
                                   where r.Id == ur.RoleId
                                   select rl.Description).ToList(),
                       TerritoryName = leftTerritory != null ? leftTerritory.Name : null,
                       CreatedDate = ub.Created.HasValue ? ub.Created.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : string.Empty,                           
                       IsActive = ub.IsActive.HasValue ? ub.IsActive : null
                   };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Note:-
When I execute the same query in SQL server, it'll work good but LINQ I'm getting timeout error or object reference error.

Normally few more values are passing on the query as a search parameter like TerritoryName, roles, it'll return some values if exists but when I pass the First name and last name as a search parameter, there is no data will be returned even if the records exist from the DB.

I don't how this has happened and which way is correct to get all those datas(nearly 144000 records) from the DB. Kindly share your views to fix it.

Comment: The typical setup for SQL Server ignores case when comparing character data.  All your ToUpper commands are going to make the CPU skyrocket.  The first thing I would do is take all those out.  When you call functions on data in the database, it really slows things down.

Comment: Try turning EF Core [Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging) on and see what actually happens. There are some suspicious things inside the query like `ub.Created.Value.Date.Equals(query)` condition and `UserRole = ...` inside the `select` that need to be checked.